# Laravel - Vue Axios CORS policy

Tags: laravel, vue.js, google-maps, axios, cors

The request

```
axios.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+this.currentLocation.lat+","+this.currentLocation.lng+"&key="+this.apiKey).then((response) => {
                        if (this.town === response.data.results[0].address_components[2].long_name){
                            return
                        }
                        else{
                            this.town = response.data.results[0].address_components[2].long_name
                            this.getSuggested();
                            this.getAllEvents();
                        }
                        
                }).catch(er => {
                    console.log(er)
                })
```

When i'm trying to get the town of a location i get this error

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'API Route' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-requested-with is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

When i remove

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

from bootstrap.js, the request works just fine.

What exactly is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any server you’re sending a request to will, usually by default, reject it if it contains headers which are not [CORS-safelisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS-safelisted_response_header).

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

This code tells axios to attach a custom header to every request. Ergo, your request is being sent with a non safelisted header, which the server won’t permit, so you receive the error.

To permit the request, the server must be configured to allow the custom header.